# How to get exact coordinates of a specific character in a JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d, jtextpane

I'm making a custom JTextArea by overriding `paintComponent` and adding extra functionality. I'm trying to figure out how to get the exact coordinates of a specific character on a JTextArea relative to that component. I could use `getFontMetrics` to measure out the text on the component, but that would be quite cumbersome. Just wondering if there is a better way of doing it.

Here's an example of what I need to do.

[image]

Comment: I think you might want to have a look at [`JTextComponent#modelToView2D`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#modelToView2D(int)) as a starting point

Comment: As well as [`Component#getLocationOnScreen`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getLocationOnScreen()) (depending on what type of 'coordinates' you were looking for).

Comment: *and adding extra functionality* - what kind of extra functionality? If you are not aware of the "modelToView(…)" method maybe you are also unaware of other methods of the text area. Since you are overriding paintComponent, it seems to me you might be trying to do highlighting of some kind, which is already supported.

Comment: @camickr No i'm not highlighting text. I'm creating a sort of auto complete with a suggestion box. Just trying out a concept.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks, `modelToView2D` worked great. I would mark it as the correct answer if you made one.

Comment: @bytes If you have a working example, you can self answer - I was just though it might help ;)

Comment: *I'm creating a sort of auto complete with a suggestion box* - I would suggest you probably should not be doing this in the paintComponent() method of the JTextArea. Instead, you get the view coordinates and add a JList (or some other Swing component) to the JTextArea with the list of values. When a value is selected you remove the component from the text area. This is basically how a popup menu works.